# Adding a click function to a image element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add 2 simple click functions to 2 images and make them "active" when clicked, however for some reason the code is not working.

This is the link to the external file:

```
<head>
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.leanModal.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="likeandshare.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="blogformat.css" />

 <script type="text/javascript" src="likeandshare.js"></script>
 </head>
```

This is the html:

```
<div class="blog-header">
<h1>This heading should be center aligned and colored</h1>
<p>Italised date and Author entered here</p>

<div id="facebook-like-button">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook_like_button_big.jpeg"></a>
</div>
<div id="facebook-share-button">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook-share.png"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the js code:

```
 $(document).ready(main);

var like = function() {
$("#facebook-like-button").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("active");
});
};
```

I'm not sure why the div is not becoming active when clicked but I would also like to attach the function ONLY to the image, rather than the entire div.

Help :D

thanks.

Comment: what is main in  $(document).ready(main);?

Comment: Good catch, the function beneath was called main but I changed it to "like" before posting. I have edited it to function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, your code should be working. You must be incorrectly calling the `ready` function.

**working example** http://jsfiddle.net/2j0s1j8v/3/

All of these events fire back:

```
share = document.getElementById("facebook-share-button");
share.onclick = function(){ 
    console.log("ONCLICK"); 
}  
share.addEventListener("click", function(){ console.log("CLICK LISTENER"); } );

$("#facebook-share-button").click(function() {
    console.log("JQUERY CLICK");
});
```

Check the console and look at the messages. All of them fire properly. f12 on chrome.

Comment: Thanks Lemony for the prompt reply. I used this code here instead and it worked fine.

Comment: @Jgz Which of the ones did you use? If you're using jQuery you should stick with jQuery. The others were just to make sure nothing fishy is going on with jQuery's handling.

Comment: I used my initial code which worked except no matter what I did, I couldn't get the "active' class to actovate when clicked. I decided for now to use CSS and use the :hover until I can debug my jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#facebook-like-button").find('img').click(function() {
         $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried this but the code is still not running. Very odd. I have a model window that opens within the HTML itself but cant get a simple click function to work :D

Answer (score 0):

first include jquery

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="likeandshare.js"></script>
</head>
```

second you create a like function and use main function .. you have a main function also or bad typo or what anyway in your case it should be

```
$(document).ready(like);
```

if you want to select an image inside the div just use > a >img

```
var like = function() {
$("#facebook-like-button > a > img").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("active");
});
};
```

Comment: For some reason, this is still not running. I will update the original post with all the code in header to see if there is a conflict.I should add that I have script code in my html for a model window as well, but there shouldnt be a conflict there.

Comment: @Jgz try to give your #facebook-like-button   overflow:hidden; in css .. and before everything read the console log for any errors

Comment: Will do. Will report back

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/2j0s1j8v/4/

Like button

```
$("#facebook-like-button img").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Share button

```
$("#facebook-share-button img").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Here is a working example if I understand correctly what you wanted.

adds active class to the image on click.

EDIT: added share as well